# Split file by pattern

Tags: regex, split

I'm having troubles splitting a file using a pattern.

My big file is a text one which looks like this

```
PATTERN
data
data
data PATTERN
```

the problem starts when the PATTERN is at the end of the line, csplit takes the whole line and puts it in the next file:

```
data_belonging_to_the_above_file PATTERN
data
data
```

I would need that the `data_belonging_to_the_above_file` should be put in the previous file

This is the command I'm using now:

```
csplit data.log /PATTERN/ {*}
```

Comment: Could you preprocess it to put the pattern on a new line always?  `sed 's/PATTERN/\nPATTERN/g' data.log | csplit ...` (assuming your `sed` dialect supports `\n` in substitutions).

Comment: I'm trying that now, it doesn't seem to work, I must be doing something wrong: sed 's/regexp/&\n/g' file.log Oh! Now I see your code above, I will try it and get back!

Comment: Thank you tripleee! Indeed it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Similar to previous comments my solution would be to preprocess your file using a replacement.
I tried this:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<!^)(PATTERN)/\n\1/mg;s/(PATTERN)(?!$)/\1\n/mg'
```

This adds a newline before the pattern if it's not at the beginning of a line, and adds a newline after the pattern if it's not at the end of a line.
I use perl because not every version of sed does support this expression.

Comment: Thanks, but I went with sed and csplit.